# Is it possible to have a matrix whose determinant is non-zero and yet is not invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Matrix should be in the set 2x2 (z/6z). The thing that is confusing me about this question is if the determinant is non-zero how can it be not invertible cause doesn't that mean its determinant is zero?
Another part of this question is does the set of invertible matrices in this group form a group?

I know the only elements that could be used in this matrix is {0,1,2,3,4,5} but other than that I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z/6$ has zero divisors and is not a field.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Dietrich Burde's comment, an example would be:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right)$$

The inverse matrix 'wants to be':
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0 & 2^{-1}\end{array}\right)$$

But $2$ has no inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 3):

For any commutative ring $R$, the set
$$
GL_2(R)=\{A\in M_2(R)\mid A \text{ is invertible over }R\}
$$
under matrix multiplication is a group. However, the equivalence of $A$ being invertible and $\det(A)\neq 0 $ in $R$ need not be correct. First of all we need $\det(A)\in R^{\times}$, i.e., the determinant is a unit in $R$. For a field $K$ the units are $K\setminus 0$, but for an arbitrary commutative ring this is quite different. For $R=\Bbb Z/6$ only the classes of $1$ and $-1=5$ are units.